# Not work UPDATE MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have mystical error with MySQL query. I'm using CI php-framework.
This is my function in controller:

```
public function editParam($id_article_params='')
{
    if(IS_AJAX)
    {
        $this->load->model('Article_params_model','article_params');
        $this->article_params->updateSizeById($id_article_params,$_GET['size']);
    }
}
```

Article_params model:

```
class Article_params_model extends CI_Model
{
     public function updateSizeById($id_article_params,$size)
     {
         $this->db->query("UPDATE article_params SET size='".$size."' WHERE id_article_params='".$id_article_params."'");
     }
}
```

I'm trying to get error but error not isset. For example, next function also in Article_params_model but work!

```
public function all()
{
    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM article_params");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Article_params model put below code.

```
class Article_params_model extends CI_Model
{
 public function updateSizeById($id_article_params,$size)
 {
    $this->db->where('id_article_params', $id_article_params);
$this->db->update('article_params', $size);
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Article_params_model extends CI_Model
{
 public function updateSizeById($id_article_params,$size)
 {
    $this->db->where('id_article_params', $id_article_params);
$this->db->update('article_params', $size);
 }
}
```